# PHP 5.4 packages are installed but the server is using PHP 5.3

Tags: centos, php5, suphp

I'm trying to upgrade PHP 5.3 to 5.4 on a CentOS 6.7 VPS. Followed the Webtatic instructions here: https://webtatic.com/packages/php54/

Now at a stage where the 5.4 packages are installed, but PHP 5.3 is still being used and lots of Internal 500 errors are being thrown when accessing PHP pages.

```
root@server [~]# yum list installed php\*
Installed Packages
php54w-cli.x86_64           5.4.43-1.w6       @webtatic
php54w-common.x86_64        5.4.43-1.w6       @webtatic
root@server [~]# php -v
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Sep  8 2014 19:48:10)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Reading around, one suggestion is that it's to do with suPHP, although checking permissions, everything seems to be correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Output of `which php`?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/php

Comment: 'file /usr/local/bin/php is not owned by any package'

Comment: seems like you have installed `php` from source and that's why there's confusion...

Answer (score 0):

The CentOS rpm-controlled `php` is `/usr/bin/php`.  You clearly have more than one version of PHP installed, and from what you've written above, it doesn't look like the alternative `php` binary is under any form of package control.  You'll have to root it out manually.

Your best bet may be to find out *why* your apache is choosing `/usr/local/bin/php` over /`usr/bin/php`, and see if you can get it to prefer the RPM-controlled version.  Note that you will almost certainly need the core `php54w` package installed as well.